# Querying a Postgres array of integers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

my model has a pg array which I use to store integers

Querying using the methods I found from other questions yields errors or gives empty results

```
MyModel.where("? = ANY (myarray)", 42)
```

gives

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text
```

and

```
 MyModel.where("myarray @> '{?}'", 42)
```

gives an empty results, yet I do have a model with 42 as one of the ints in the array

```
#<MyModel:0x007f9a77dd5608> {
                :id => 170,
      :myarray => [
    [0] 42,
    [1] 43,
    [2] 58,
    [3] 61,
    [4] 63
  ]
```

Is there a special way to query integers(or floats) within a postgres array in Rails?

the migration

```
class AddMyarrayToMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :my_models, :myarray, :integer, array: true, default: []
    add_index  :my_models, :myarray, using: 'gin'
  end
end
```

and schema

```
t.integer  "myarray",                 default: [],              array: true
```

Answer (score 20):

Try these:

```
MyModel.where("? = ANY(myarray)", '{42}')
```

or

```
MyModel.where("myarray @> ?", '{42}')
```

or (on PG 9.6 according to York Yang's comment)

```
MyModel.where("? = ANY(myarray)", '42')
```

Comment: Can you add the migration file or the schema?

Comment: MyModel.where("? = ANY(myarray)", '{42}') should be MyModel.where("? = ANY(myarray)", '42') ? tested on pg 9.6

Answer (score 1):

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text

From this message it appears that the `myarray` is *actually* an array of type `text`. Check that column to make sure it is of the correct type.

Comment: And if it's true try `MyModel.where("'?' = ANY(myarray)", 42)`

Answer (score 0):

seems to had a problem with the name of the array since there was an association with a similar name and rails automagic collided with it